# sfdx data:tree:export objects with relation

Tags: salesforcedx, data-export

Here is the scructure I have:

**Condition__c**:

- ... fields

**Account**:

- Lookup to Condition
- ... fields

**Invoice__c**:

- Master detail to Account
- ... fields

**Invoice_Line__c**:

- Master detail to Invoice
- ... fields

Query is **like**:

```
SELECT 
  Id, {fields} , Account__c, Account__r.{fields},
  Account__r.Condition__c, Account__r.Condition__r.{fields},
  ( SELECT Id, {fields} FROM Invoice_Lines__r )
FROM Invoice__c
```

**Command**:

`sfdx force:data:tree:export -q ./soql/query_file.soql --prefix export-demo -d ./data --plan`

**Result**:

> ERROR:  Reference Account not found for Account__c.  Skipping record a045E000002TEuDQAW.
>   Wrote 1 records to data\export-demo-Invoice__cs.json
>   Wrote 1 records to data\export-demo-Invoice_Line__cs.json
>   Wrote 0 records to data\export-demo-Invoice__c-Invoice_Line__c-plan.json

So I tried to first export the account as this:

```
SELECT 
  Id, Name, Intracommunity__c,Condition__c, Condition__r.{fields}
FROM Account
```

And the result is:

> ERROR:  Reference Condition__c not found for Condition__c.  Skipping record 0015E00000aL0FmQAK.
>   Wrote 1 records to data\export-demo-Accounts.json
>   Wrote 0 records to data\export-demo-Account-plan.json

Is there a way relationship between exported records ?

Answer (score 2):

You must find the Child Relationship Name. So e.g. for Invoice, go to the Invoice object, find the relationship field to Account and get the *Child Relationship Name*, e.g. Invoices. That's the name you'd use in the query.

Then you'd use `"SELECT something...., (SELECT something FROM Invoices) FROM Account"`, and have the --plan parameter as you already suggest. So none of the `__r` names.